# Branch checkout directory with Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I have 3 build configurations: windows, osx and ubuntu. I also have two branches (generally): master and next. I've configured TC so that whenever a checkin occurs on either of the branches, the 3 builds are kicked off. I also have a 4th config called deploy which pushes the builds to a staging server.

The problem I'm having is that when a build is kicked off for refs/heads/next followed by a build for refs/heads/master, Teamcity cleans the entire checkout directory which causes a full rebuild for no good reason. Given that my builds take place on EC2, this literally costs me money.

In the past, I've copied and pasted configurations so I'd have osx-master, ubuntu-master, windows-master, osx-next, ubuntu-next, windows-next but when I need to do a change, it gets annoying fast and it is difficult to make significant changes.

Now, what is the best way to avoid rebuilds for the reasons I've described above? Any suggestions?

Thanks and I hope this question makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom folder for checkout branch, so each branch is checkout in its own folder, that would avoid rebuilding sources.

Comment: Aha. I set it to this and hope it works - will report back:%teamcity.build.default.checkoutDir%-%teamcity.build.branch%